# Display prime number

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, input, primes

This programming I wrote below is used to display prime number from a list (20 numbers) which keyed in by user. But it only can detect 2 and 3 as prime number. I don't know why it doesn't work. Please tell me where is the errors and help me improve it. TQ.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

void main ()
{
    int i,number,list[20];
    int t,p,prime=0;


    cout<<"please key 20 numbers from 0 to 99"<<endl;


    for(i=1;i<21;i++)
    {
        cin>>number;

        if((number<0)||(number>99))
        {
            cout<<"Please key in an integer from 0 to 99"<<endl;

        }

        list[i]=number;

    }


    for(p=1;p<21;p++)
    {
        for(t=2;t<list[p];t++)
        {
            if ( list[p]%t==0)
            {
                prime=prime+1;
            }
        }
            if (prime==0&&list[p]!=1)
            {
                cout<<"Prime numbers:"<<list[p]<<endl;
            }
    }

getch();
}
```

Comment: `< 21` is an invitation to undefined behaviour; your `list` has 20 elements, so the loops should be similar to `for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)`.  You're also studiously ignoring element 0 in the array; that need not be a problem, but effectively wastes one element of the array.

Comment: You need to set `prime = 0;` before the start of the inner loop.  As for improvements, look up Sieve of Eratosthenes or almost any other question about prime numbers on SO.  Your code is just about is inefficient as a prime test can be.

Comment: I have done so, refer the 8th row.

Comment: What I mean is "You need to set `prime = 0;` as the first statement in the body of the outer `for` loop, before the start of the inner `for` loop".  You set it to zero at the beginning of the program.  When you enter 2, `prime` is never incremented, so you correctly identify 2 as prime; ditto 3.  When you enter 4, `prime` is incremented, so it is identified as composite.  When you enter 5, though, prime is non-zero so it is deemed to be composite.

Comment: Compile your program with all warnings & debug info, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then **use a debugger** e.g. `gdb` to run your program step by step. Read about [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) & [prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)

Comment: Oo...ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please check for relevant answers posted in SO , also set prime = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few issues with your code, but the one that will solve your issue is simply algorithmic.

When you start at the next iteration of p, you don't reset the value of prime and therefore it's always > 0 after we detect the second prime number and you'll never print out any again.

Change this:

```
for(p=1;p<21;p++)
{
    for(t=2;t<list[p];t++)
    {
        if ( list[p]%t==0)
        {
            prime=prime+1;
        }
    }
        if (prime==0&&list[p]!=1)
        {
            cout<<"Prime numbers:"<<list[p]<<endl;
        }
}
```

To this (I've added some brackets for clairty and so we're certain the condition evaluates as we expect it to):

```
for(p=0;p<20;p++)
{
    for(t=2;t<list[p];t++)
    {
        if ( list[p]%t==0)
        {
            prime=prime+1;
        }
    }
        if ( (prime==0) && (list[p]!=1) )
        {
            cout<<"Prime numbers:"<<list[p]<<endl;
        }
        prime = 0;
}
```

And your issue will be solved.

HOWEVER: I would like to reiterate this does not solve all of your code issues. Make sure you think very carefully about the input part and what you are looping over (why is p 1 to 21? Why not 0 to 20 ;) arrays are zero indexed in C meaning that your list of 20 numbers goes from list[0] to list[19], you're currently looping from list[1] to list[20] which is actually out of range and I'm surprised you didn't get a segfault!)

Comment: I do not know that will be a problem. However, since you all advise me to make the iteration start with 0, then, I will comply with. Thank you.

Comment: There are two issues with not doing it.

Firstly, you're ignoring the first element in the list. You start the iterations at p=1 which is list[1] which is the second element in your list, potentially missing a prime number.

Secondly, going to p<21 means the final element checked is list[20] which doesn't actually exist because you only have a list of 20 elements which finish at list[19] (because C is zero indexed).

Doing this iteration any other way than from p=0 to p=19 will result in unwanted and undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm a beginner, many rules are not quite understand. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: It would be even better to set `prime = 0;` before the inner loop. Indeed, you could use `int prime = 0;` to define and initialize it as the first 'statement' after the open brace of the outer loop.  'Statement' in quotes because it is technically a declaration (definition), but it is functionally a statement.  You can do that even with pre-standard C; variables can be declared at the top of a statement block (after an `{`).  C99 and later allows you to define variables when you need them.  Limiting the scope of a variable is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int n, i = 3, count, c;

   printf("Enter the number of prime numbers required\n");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   if ( n >= 1 )
   {
      printf("First %d prime numbers are :\n",n);
      printf("2\n");
   }

   for ( count = 2 ; count <= n ;  )
   {
      for ( c = 2 ; c <= i - 1 ; c++ )
      {
         if ( i%c == 0 )
            break;
      }
      if ( c == i )
      {
         printf("%d\n",i);
         count++;
      }
      i++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit my code such that it can be run well? Your code is tooooooooo deep, I cannot understand.

Comment: check this one  http://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/examples/prime-number-intervals

Comment: I checked, but I still cannot understand why my code does not working. Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

What happens in your code is someone types in "123" or "-15"?  Check and see if you can fix the error.

When you have fixed that, we can look at your prime checking code.  Hint: there are a lot of prime testing code examples on the web.

Answer (score 0):

**More Efficient Way**

```
def print_hi(n):
if(n == 1 ):
    return False;
if( n == 2 or n == 3):
    return True;
if(n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0):
    return  False;

for i in range (5,n,6):
    if( i * i <= n):
        if(n % i == 0 or n % (i+2) == 0):
            return False
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
  x = print_hi(1032)
  print(x)
```